# Im trying to insert many rows at once in my DB but im getting an error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, axios, laravel-8

im trying to insert many rows at once in my MySQL db with Laravel 8 and axios but im getting this error [image]

[image]

this is my db table called auroracoins [image]

the api where im taking the data is like this [image]

Here is my axios call

```
       async insertar(history_records) {
            try {
                console.log(history_records)
                const response = await axios
                    .post("/home/insert", history_records.results)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log("worked")
                        // this.categories.push(this.categoryToAdd);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                this.request_status = error;
                console.log(error);
            }
        },
```

that is the web.php route [image]

Here is the store function [![enter image description here][7]][7]

PD:Sorry for using images instead of code, but im having some formating problems

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    error_log($request);

    //Create item


    foreach ($request as $history_record) {

        $history = new Auroracoin();
        $history->history_date = $history_record->date;
        $history->rate = $history_record->rate;
    }

    $history->save();

    return $history;
}
```

Comment: `Sorry for using images instead of code, but im having some formating problems`...fix the formatting problems then. As per [ask], images of code are unhelpful and unwelcome. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting if you need assistance with how to display your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont loop the $request directly, it's a symfony Request object.

To loop the data you're sending, use

```
foreach ($request->all() as $history_record) {
    $history = new Auroracoin();
    $history->history_date = $history_record['date'];
    $history->rate = $history_record['rate'];
}
```

Event tho the data is send as a json object, there is no such thing in http. you need to access them as associative array `$history_record['date']`

The `$request->all()` return an array with all the POST/GET data sent with the request.

Comment: Thanks N69S that worked perfectly and now i understand :D